# RTSP stream exited with error": Connection timed out

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, rtsp

I am building an web application on AWS Cloud that requires to stream a recorded/live video over the global network. I purchased an IP camera(GV-AVD4710) and NVR(GV-SNVR0811) for our application. In future I need to stream no. of cameras on my application.

While Camera in use With NVR, I have connected the NVR in our local network and the camera at channel_1 of NVR. Now the lets assume NVR is getting an IP of 192.168.1.203. So for rtsp streaming URL for channel_1 will be `"rtsp://id:password@192.168.1.203:554/ch1"` as per manufacturer's specification. For camera streaming I am using "ffmpeg" multimedia framework (https://github.com/xpcrts/Steaming-IP-Camera-Nodejs ). So it is working fine. I tested it and working well in local network. Code that is running on the server

```
Stream = require('node-rtsp-stream')
stream = new Stream({
    name: 'name',
    streamUrl: 'rtsp://ID:PASSWORD@abcxyz.com:554/ch1',
    wsPort:3000,
    ffmpegOptions: {
        '-stats': '',
        '-r': 30
    }
})
```

and Code running at client side which is independent of any plug-ins

```
<div>
       <canvas id="chanel1" width="auto" height="auto"></canvas>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="jsmpeg.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
            var canvas = document.getElementById('chanel1');
            var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://34.202.222.188:3000");
            var player= new jsmpeg(websocket, {canvas:canvas, autoplay:true, loop:true})
       </script>
</div>
```

When I made this IP address available for public, and then the problem begins. It is not working and giving an error:

```
 "[tcp @ 0x563911f0a340] Connection to tcp://192.168.1.205:554?timeout=0 failed: Connection timed out
rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.205: Connection timed out RTSP stream exited with error"
```

In Camera Without NVR, I connected camera directly to our local network and so got an rtsp url like rtsp://id:password@192.168.1.205/media/video1. Same happens again. Works well in local, but not working when I am making this available on public network.

How can stream video over global network? Is it possible to implement these logic using ffmpeg multimedia framework? Does VLC can help in these cases?

I would like to reiterate that, In future there are no. of cameras needs to be stream.